# How to access a Lotus iNotes mailbox hosted only on a server with python?

Tags: python, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, win32com, lotusscript

I am trying to access a Lotus iNotes mailbox to download some attachments files via a python script.

The mailbox is hosted only on the company server.  I access it with an url which looks like :

https://the_company_server.com/mail/db.nsf

I read multiple threads here and on other websites using the win32com.client python library, but it seems to work only with local LotusNotes nsf databases, not for iNotes mailbox.

Do you know if it's possible to do such thing ? If there is, which python library could perform that ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you use rest api ?

Answer (score 0):

The Notes COM classes can access any remote Domino server that a Notes client installed on the same machine can access. It is not limited just to local NSF files. But you *must* have the Lotus Notes client or Domino Server software installed on the machine where the code runs. That's the only way to get to the Notes core DLLs that provide services to the API. Once you have that set up properly, the [GetDatabase method](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_10.0.0/basic/H_GETDATABASE_METHOD.html) in the [NotesSession class](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_10.0.0/basic/H_NOTESSESSION_CLASS.html) takes the name of a remote Domino server as it's first argument. The server name used in this call is the one that matches the server's ID file and is used by the Notes client; it is not necessarily the same as the DNS name that is used in URL that you are using for iNotes access. And, obviously, you may need to work through some firewall issues in order for this to work if you are trying to access the server from outside the organization's network.

BTW, there are both COM classes and OLE classes. The COM classes are rooted in Lotus.NotesSession and the OLE classes are rooted in Notes.NotesUIWorkspace and Notes.NotesSession. The major difference is that the COM classes do not require that you actually run the Notes client; it just has to be installed and configured. The OLE classes will start the Notes client if it is not already running.